# How avoid the single quotation issue from java to create prepared statment query

Tags: java, hibernate, prepared-statement

***Example: Update EMPLOYEES set NAME = ''EMP123'' where ID = 100;***

Here NAME field is alternately given by user may be user gives the name with single quotes. it was shown the error like
**ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended**

Comment: Do not build SQL by concatenating strings. Use `PreparedStatement` with substitution placeholders.

Comment: @ Jim Garrison actually in this prepared statement is dynamically given by user may be user gives the single quotes or not.

Comment: Allowing users to give you sql is a really bad idea. If you must, then it's up to the users to provide proper SQL syntax, you cannot expect to fix errors they make.

Answer (score 0):

```
PreparedStatement stm = connection.prepareStatement("Update EMPLOYEES set NAME = ? where ID = 100");    
stm.setString(1,"EMP123");
System.out.println(stm.executeUpdate()+" Rows has changed");
```

this how you should do it to protectect your code from sql injection attack